# How can I ditch Google, on Android?

Tags: android

I've gotten to the point where I no longer trust Google to provide me with a reliable service that doesn't spy on me. Google sees to be able to close your account without warning because you've violated some nebulous "terms of service", after which you lose access to anything stored on "Someone else's computer" (i.e. The Cloud).  Apple isn't an alternative for me, and doesn't seem much better.

So what are the alternatives to the basic Android apps that come up the phone? I'd need to replace the photo-sync software, messaging, Maps, email, and of course Google Play itself.

My goal is to not be logged into Google at all on my phone, and to have a service that both respects my privacy, and won't suddenly cut me off from if I do something they don't like.

Doing a little bit of research on this question, I see some 5+ year old similar questions for each individual app, but not a holistic "I want to get rid of Google entirely on Android" question.

Hopefully the monopoly power of Google isn't so powerful this is possible? I suspect Google Play is going to be nearly impossible to extricate my phone from.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you [put each question in a separate question post](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154). Please [edit] your post down to one question, and create new posts to ask any further questions. You'll get better answers that way. Apart from that, for a general approach, use a search engine to look for "[Android without Google](https://duckduckgo.com/?q="android+without+google")". Plenty of blogs on this. I've switched to LineageOS and F-Droid years ago and am quite happy with that.

Comment: PS: "each question" in the context of my previous comment means, each specific app you need. Including what features you require, etc. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for a guide. Further, for apps you can check [with my lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists). Watch out for yellow stars ("no trackers") and F-Droid icons next to the apps ;)

Comment: Short hints: Google Play => F-Droid; Mail => FairEmail or K-9; Maps: OsmAnd; Messaging => very much depends. I use Conversations (XMPP) and Threema (not on F-Droid) – but there's also Matrix/Riot/Element, Signal, Briar [and more](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_messenger).

Comment: Related : [How can I escape Google?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187982/how-can-i-escape-google)

Answer (score 6):

There are versions of Android which don't include Google software. [LineageOS with microg](https://lineage.microg.org/) would work. This is a full Android OS, with a compatibility layer that reproduces the Google Play Services API which many apps depend on.

There is also a new OS called [/e/](https://e.foundation/) which might do the same thing and has an app store.